# MetaMask/mascara integration for no metamask users

Tags: metamask, ethjs

I am creating iframe based metamask. [github source](https://github.com/MetaMask/mascara)

HTML

```
<script src="https://wallet.metamask.io/metamascara.js"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/ethjs-query.min.js"></script>
```

Javascript

```
var ethereumProvider;
var ethQuery;
if (typeof web3 === 'undefined')
 {    
    async function loadProvider() {
      const ethereumProvider = metamask.createDefaultProvider()
      ethQuery = new Eth(ethereumProvider)
>>>>  const accounts = await ethQuery.accounts();
      window.METAMASK_ACCOUNT = accounts[0] || 'locked'
      logToDom(accounts.length ? accounts[0] : 'LOCKED or undefined', 'account')
    }
    loadProvider();
    function logToDom(message, context){
      console.log(message)
    }
}
```

on `>>>>` part, it is providing error:

> [ethjs-query] method 'accounts' requires at least undefined input
>   (format type undefined), 0 provided.

I am quite new to `ethjs-query`, and could not find any solution for 10 hours.

It would be much appreciate if someone help me with my issue.